# unable to to poll the message from the kafka server by using the consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

while I run the java code use the kafka comsumer to poll the message from the kafka server, it always show 0 message,

the kafka server log shows the group error:

```
[2022-09-08 05:03:03,785] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Dynamic Member with unknown member id joins group KafkaStudy in Empty state. Created a new member id consumer-1-e99d5a30-346b-4e26-8ff5-7f0e5fac3e9b for this member and add to the group. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2022-09-08 05:03:03,785] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group KafkaStudy in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 27 (__consumer_offsets-15) (reason: Adding new member consumer-1-e99d5a30-346b-4e26-8ff5-7f0e5fac3e9b with group instance id None; client reason: not provided) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2022-09-08 05:03:03,788] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Stabilized group KafkaStudy generation 28 (__consumer_offsets-15) with 1 members (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2022-09-08 05:03:03,809] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Assignment received from leader consumer-1-e99d5a30-346b-4e26-8ff5-7f0e5fac3e9b for group KafkaStudy for generation 28. The group has 1 members, 0 of which are static. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2022-09-08 05:03:13,819] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Member consumer-1-e99d5a30-346b-4e26-8ff5-7f0e5fac3e9b in group KafkaStudy has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2022-09-08 05:03:13,820] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Preparing to rebalance group KafkaStudy in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 28 (__consumer_offsets-15) (reason: removing member consumer-1-e99d5a30-346b-4e26-8ff5-7f0e5fac3e9b on heartbeat expiration) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2022-09-08 05:03:13,821] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1]: Group KafkaStudy with generation 29 is now empty (__consumer_offsets-15) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

the below are code:

```
 Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers","192.168.226.133:9092");
        properties.put("key.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        properties.put("value.deserializer","org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
        properties.put("enable.auto.commit", true);
        properties.put("group.id","KafkaStudy");
        properties.put("group.instance.id","1");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
        consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("quickstart-events"));

        try{
               ConsumerRecords<String,String> records = consumer.poll(100);
                for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {System.out.println(record.value());}

            } finally{
            consumer.close();
        }
```

Comment: there's clearly something wrong as per this log message you sent:  in group KafkaStudy has failed, removing it from the group
but the piece of code you sent is not enough to find out the reason. 
Need more detailed logging with possible error messages and more complete code.

Comment: There is no error in your logs

Answer (score 0):

By default, the consumer starts at the end of the topic. You need a new group id with

```
properties.put("auto.offset.reset","earliest");
```

Or produce data while consumer is running.